# Tidying up tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I've been looking at some of the lesser used tags and proposing tag synonyms.  I've found several in tags that I don't have five upvotes for yet, but that look like they might be good synonyms.  If you have sufficient upvotes in any of the following tags, please consider proposing a synonym if you think it's a good fit.

[wording](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wording) <-- [verb](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb) 
[screen-orientation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-orientation) <-- [viewport-orientation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewport-orientation) 
[graphics](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) <-- [aliasing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliasing) 
[graphics](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) <-- [moire](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moire) 
[ordering](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordering) <-- [graduations](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduations) 
<del>[close](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close) <-- [exit](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit)</del> 
[click](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/click) <-- [tap](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tap) 
[standards](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards) <-- [authority](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authority) 
[planning](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) <-- [ux-plans](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-plans) 
<del>[information-architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-architecture) <-- [architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture)</del> 
[agile-development](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile-development) <-- [lean-ux](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lean-ux) 
[info-visualization](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/info-visualization) <-- [viewer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer) 
[customisation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customisation) <-- [customizable](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customizable) 
[actions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions) <-- [action](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action)

Comment: Mods can just immediately approve theses synonyms if the apparent consensus is pro-synonym

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't agree on [click](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/click) <- [tap](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tap) only because questions about tagged [tap](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tap) are going to be for touch devices and there is enough difference there to warrant it's own tag in my opinion.

Same with [information-architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-architecture) <- [architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture).  In this case I would just retag questions that are IA (which I [have](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8267/methods-for-evaluating-a-complex-information-architecture) [done](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24757/how-can-i-improve-my-information-architecture-skills)).  Whether we need an [architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) tag at all I would say is up for debate.

If anything, [physical](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical) <- [architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) might be more appropriate.

Comment: I noticed you just re-tagged three of the five [tag:architecture] questions to [tag:information-architecture].  Isn't it reasonable to assume based on that past tagging that future users might also enter [tag:architecture] meaning [tag:information-architecture]?  Or should we also retag the two remaining [tag:architecture] questions as [tag:physical] and get rid of the [tag:architecture] tag because of its inherent ambiguity?

Comment: My problem with Architecture and tap are that they're mostly covered by Physical and Touch-screen in practice.

Comment: @Ben: Perhaps merging physical <- architecture and touch-screen <- tap would be best.

Comment: @3nafish: architecture has no summary so that doesn't help users know what it means.  Because there are questions in there that are not IA, I don't think you can make the argument that all architecture tags are IA automatically.  I think architecture as a tag should be merged, but with the remaining items, the merger should be with physical.

Comment: @CharlesWesley But there are also future taggings to take into account.  If we list architecture as a synonym of physical, people writing architecture to mean information architecture would be mis-tagging their questions.  Moving the two current posts to physical (and removing architecture as a tag) might prevent such errors, unless someone creates the tag again.

Comment: I am in favor of merging and getting rid of architecture entirely, so future tagging wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Sounds good.  I've retagged the two remaining architecture questions as just "physical."